# Using OAuth2 for service's own web interface (password grant?)

Tags: rest, single-page-application, oauth-2.0

My web service exposes subset of it's API through OAuth2 mechanism. Service's own web interface is implemented as single page web app and uses the superset of those API using kind of access tokens too. Can I use OAuth2 for service's own interface? What OAuth2 flow should I use? I have two options: implicit grant and password grant. I prefer direct password grant (it works almost like classic web app authorization protocol and allows refresh tokens). How can I restrict access with these tokens to app own interface only?